# How to obtain system and user information from a mounted VMDK file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, virtual-machine

Looking for some help with obtaining (grabbing) data from a VMDK file that is mounted under (Ubuntu 20.04) Linux. The challenge is to mount the VMDK file and use CLI to obtain information on the VMDK installed Linux system instead of spinning it up in a VM or using Forensics tools on it.

There are things I was able to obtain such as **os-release**, **timezone**, **hostname**, and **filesystem** type.

I achieved it using the following commands:

- `cat /mnt/vmdisk/etc/os-release`,
- `cat /mnt/vmdisk/etc/hostname`,
- `cat /mnt/vmdisk/etc/timezone`,
- `df -Th`

While `df -Th` shows all drives, I could pinpoint **/dev/loop5** which has **/mnt/vmdisk** under it to be **ext4** filesytem. Which would make sense as the VMDK is for Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS image.

Here is where I'm unsure where to look and what to run. I need to collect the following data as well.

1. How do I obtain "last" system IP?
2. Whose account is UID XXXX?
3. On X date what IP did UID XXXX authenticate from?
4. Last command used by user?

For #2 I think I could just use `cat /mnt/vmdisk/etc/passwd` or `grep 'xxxx' /mnt/vmdisk/etc/passwd`. However I'm not 100% certain fetching UID out of /etc/passwd would be the right place.

Suggestions on how to collect this data would be beyond helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're doing forensics.

1. If it's static it's in `/etc/network/interfaces` if it's dynamic it's in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`
2. `/etc/passwd`
3. `/var/log/auth.log`,`/var/log/wtmp`, `/var/log/btmp`, `/var/log/lastlog`
4. `/home/$USERNAME/.bash_history` - might **not** be necessarily there. If it's a different shell, the log file will be different.

It can all be googled in a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you. Honestly would not be asking if I could find it. I looked at auth.log, problem is that it's listing UID=0 which is Root, while I need 1000 :)